# join tables and show all rows on table one table, but doesn't show when I use criteria in where

Tags: ms-access, left-join, outer-join

have tbl50 shows 50 rows

```
num
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8    
all the way to 50
...
```

Have 2nd query evtable that shows the numbers, category, date

```
eroder      ecategory    edate
1           beginner    02/25/2017
2           beginner    02/25/2017
3           beginner    02/25/2017
4           beginner    02/25/2017
5           Intermediate 02/25/2017
5           beginner    02/25/2017
6           beginner    02/25/2017
6           intermediate 02/25/2017
```

if i join the 2 it will show all 1-50 with the information there, but when I put criteria in the where, it will only show what is

```
SELECT tbl50.num, evtable.edate, evtable.ecategory, evtable.eorder
FROM evtable RIGHT  outer JOIN tbl50 ON evtable.eorder= tbl50.num
WHERE (((evtable.edate)=#3/5/2017#) and ((evtable.ecategory)="beginner")
```

I want the qry to show the following information

```
num eroder      ecategory    edate
1    1       beginner    02/25/2017
2    2       beginner    02/25/2017
3    3      beginner    02/25/2017
4    4       beginner    02/25/2017
5    5      beginner    02/25/2017
6    6      beginner    02/25/2017
7    
8
9
10 .....all the way to 50
```

is this possible through a query? .  I know mysql, but this is an access query.

Comment: It looks like you're doing a right outer join when you want a left outer join. Also, to be clear, you want it to show the rows where the (date = 3/5/2017 and category = beginner) or there's nothing in the right table? In that case you should check if the right join field (eorder) is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

SELECT tbl50.num, evtable.edate, evtable.ecategory, evtable.eroder FROM tbl50 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM evtable WHERE ecategory = 'begineer') evtable ON num = eroder;

Comment: The worked perfectly.  I was close, just didn't think about putting the select statement in the join.